# Sort and Join with letters and numbers

Tags: sort, join

I have two files (file1 and file2) and I would like to mount a third (file3) containing a column that the two do not have. I usually do the sort and then together with the join.
But it is not working, because it has values with letters and numbers from the example below:

File1:

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-1180 14 20574088
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11805 12 14897445
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11852 1 34309921
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11867 13 12616676
```

File2

```
AC16359 ARS-BFGL-BAC-11798 B B
AC16359 ARS-BFGL-BAC-11805 B B
AC16359 ARS-BFGL-BAC-1180 B B
AC16359 ARS-BFGL-BAC-11852 A A
AC16359 ARS-BFGL-BAC-11867 B B
```

I notice that I use the same sort command for both and note that the final SNP_Name 11805 is above 1180 and the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the matching fields only (i.e. -k1,1 for file1 and -k2,2 for file2).

e.g.

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2  <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k2,2 file2) 
ARS-BFGL-BAC-1180 14 20574088 AC16359 B B
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11805 12 14897445 AC16359 B B
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11852 1 34309921 AC16359 A A
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11867 13 12616676 AC16359 B B
```

I initially tried this using just a version sort (`-V`, `--version-sort`, which is a non-standard option which requires either GNU or *BSD sort).  That worked too, both with and without the `-k1,1` and `-k2,2`, but it may not work reliably with a larger or different set of data files.

Given that the key fields can contain either 4 or 5 digit numbers (and possibly more variations), using a [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) is ideal.  So, I'd use a version sort **and** specify the key fields.

```
join -1 1 -2 2  <(sort -V -k1,1 file1) <(sort -V -k2,2 file2)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.
My mistake was that I was doing -k2.1. Please, why is it 2 (-k, 2,2)?

Comment: because, for `-k`, both numbers (i.e. are before and after the comma) are field numbers, not a field number and a count.  `-k[start field],[stop field]`, not `-k[start],[count]`.   See `man sort` and search for "KEYDEF" for details.